# App Crash when setting ListView background

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I am trying to create a kind of cards layout for my app. Under activity_events, I need to set list_row as the background for each item in the list. As is below, the app crashes upon calling the activity. But removing JUST the `ListView android:background="@layout/list_row"` causes everything to work, just not look right. I already tried moving list_row to the drawable folder and using `@drawable/list_row`, which did not work either. Are there some limits to backgrounds in List Views that I just don't understand?

Below is `activity_events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"    
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@layout/list_row">
    </ListView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/eventsProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Below is `list_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >
<!-- ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:padding="3dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:src="@drawable/barjinx_logo" /> <!--Removal makes it work!-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is `list_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
```

Comment: Post the exception report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't use a layout as a background. You can only use a `Color` or `Drawable`.

The row layout is set in your `ListAdapter.getView()`.

**EDIT**

Your ListView should look like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"    
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
</ListView>
```

In order to style the list rows, you need to create a `ListAdapter`. Since you are using a custom layout, you will need to extend `ArrayAdapter<?>` or `BaseAdapter` and then call `ListView.setListAdapter(ListAdapter)` on your `ListView`. Check out [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown) from Vogella.

Comment: So is there no way I can nest a layout inside of another layout without making a behemoth monster layout? and I did try using it as a drawable but it didn't seem to like that. Would ' android:src ' be a better option? I don't actually know much about layouts, very new at this.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, and be sure to check out the article linked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put a background on `ListView`, you need to set an adapter (extend `BaseAdapter`) to the `ListView` and have it return your layout from `getView()` (you can use `LayoutInflater` class to inflate your `R.layout.list_row`)

**EDIT**: more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)